# How to make value persist in Controller MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following code in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string date)
        {
            var topsong = db.TopSongs;
            var topDate = db.TopDates;

            var latestDate = topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();


           if (date == "PreviousDate")
            {
                latestDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate.Date).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();                
            }

            if (date == "NextDate")
            {
                latestDate = topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();
            }           
.... 
return View();

}
```

Here is code in View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { date = "PreviousDate" }) <br />
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { date = "NextDate" })
```

If user click on PreviousDate it is sent back to controller and it chooses the previous date. First time it works fine. Problem comes the second time. As latestDate is calculated again but it should basically use PreviousDate as latestDate not calculate latestDate again. Is there a way to persist PreviousDate? Or pass it back from the View?

Here is an example:
If latestDate is 08/27/2012 first time it is loaded when i press previousDate it loads date 08/25/2012 but when i press PreviousDate again instead of using 08/25/2012 as latestDate it again uses 08/27/2012 as latest date.

TopDate class:

```
public class Top10Date
    {
        [Key]
        public int DateId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to pass the current date that is being shown as well as the "sub-action" of PreviousDate and NextDate back to the controller.

In the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string date, DateTime? latestDate)
    {
        var topsong = db.TopSongs;
        var topDate = db.TopDates;

        if (!latestDate.HasValue)
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());


       if (date.Value == "PreviousDate")
        {
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate.Date).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());                
        }

        if (date.Value == "NextDate")
        {
            latestDate = (DateTime?)(topDate.Where(d => d.Date > latestDate.Date).OrderBy(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        .... 

        ViewBag.latestDate = latestDate

        return View();
    }
```

And then

```
@Html.ActionLink("Previous Week's Songs", "Index", new { date = "PreviousDate", ViewBag.latestDate }) <br />
@Html.ActionLink("Next Week's Songs", "Index", new { date = "NextDate", ViewBag.latestDate })
```

Comment: Or as @kd7 suggests above, you could use (should?) use a ViewModel instead of the ViewBag

Comment: I like the above solution you provided i will not need much code change in this case. But latestDate.Date is not working using above solution. Any ideas?

Comment: It is because the latestDate is a nullable datetime

Comment: Still now working getting an error: cannot implicitly convert Models.Top10.Date to System.DateTime?

Comment: What is the Type of Top10.Date?  Maybe it is a timestamp.

Comment: Whatever the Type is, just change the datetime? parameter to the same type as Top10.Date - e.g. `int? latestDate` or `timespan? latestDate`

Comment: -Top10.Date is a value picked from the database. It is timestamp.

Comment: Matt Tew Even if i put in int? I get error saying < operator cannot be applied to int?

Comment: It must be stored as some type of Object by your c# code.  It depends on your ORM layer what that is.  I would perhaps try `long? previousDate`

Comment: Sorry, scratch the last few comments - it probably is a datetime.  I see my mistake.  Use `latestDate.Value =` instead.  I'll update my example

Comment: I tried latestDate.Value:                 latestDate.Value = top10Date.Where(d => d.Date < latestDate.Value.Date).OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).FirstOrDefault();                but still now working i kind of give up :) dont know what else to try.

Comment: Still same error cannot convert type Model.TopDate to DateTime?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15873/discussion-between-noviceme-and-matt-tew)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do:

```
return View(latestDate);
```

So the model binder picks it up

Comment: I am already using return View to pass back Ienumerable return View(Songs); Can i pass back two values?

Comment: Yes Create a ViewModel that has both of the properties you need. Like SongDateViewModel -> in that have a date property and Songs of whatever type. Have your Controller return the ViewModel. ViewModel is a way you can pass more complex types